# Error in processing.run("gdalogr:cliprastermymasklayer")

Tags: pyqgis, gdal

I wrote a QGIS plugin including the "gdalogr:cliprastermymasklayer" algorithm but get the following error message:

[image]

That's the code where I used the algorithm:

```
    def clipRasters(self):
    inputDir = self.getInputPath()
    outputDir = self.getOutputPath()
    for lyr in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputDir, "*xyz")):
        processing.run("gdalogr:cliprastermymasklayer", lyr, self.getVectorLayer(), 'none', True, False, 0,
                       outputDir + lyr)
```

Though, the error message is not specifically refering to my usage of the algorithm, I guess that's where the problem is.

Now, when I look at the following QGIS Dokumentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#clip-raster-by-mask-layer, it seems that I could even give 9 arguments. Thus, why does it say in the error message that I can use only 6? Or does the message not refer to the number of arguments for the gdal algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the parameters should be inside a [single dictionary](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html):

```
processing.run("gdalogr:cliprastermymasklayer", 
  { lyr, 
    self.getVectorLayer(), 
    'none', 
    True, 
    False, 
    0,
    outputDir + lyr
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the algorithm name.

You wrote `gdalogr:cliprastermymasklayer` instead of `gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer`

Your code:

```
def clipRasters(self):
inputDir = self.getInputPath()
outputDir = self.getOutputPath()
for lyr in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputDir, "*xyz")):
    processing.run("gdalogr:cliprastermymasklayer", lyr, self.getVectorLayer(), 'none', True, False, 0,
                   outputDir + lyr)
```

Should be:

```
def clipRasters(self):
inputDir = self.getInputPath()
outputDir = self.getOutputPath()
for lyr in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputDir, "*xyz")):
    processing.run("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", lyr, self.getVectorLayer(), 'none', True, False, 0,
                   outputDir + lyr)
```

Comment: Thanks Gob Tron, both comments solved one error but JGH's comment specifically resolved the error message I put in the question, so I choose his answer for the green check. But still Thanks to you as well, both answers are equally helpful in the end.