# PyQGIS error message: algorithm "gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer" not found

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I wrote a QGIS plugin and at the moment I'm going through the error messages. 
I'm stuck on the following:

[image]

Now I show you the top of my code where I import everything and the function containing the gdal algorithm:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QFileDialog
from qgis.core import *
from osgeo import gdal
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
import glob, os.path
from .resources import *
from .Clip_XYZ_dialog import ClipXYZDialog


def clipRasters(self):
    Processing.initialize()
    inputDir = self.getInputPath()
    outputDir = self.getOutputPath()
    for lyr in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputDir, "*xyz")):
        processing.run("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", {lyr, self.getVectorLayer(), 'none', True, False, 0,
                       outputDir + lyr})
```

Interesting is that "from osgeo import gdal" is actually grayed out in my code and processing has a red underline that marks some sort of error. It says "unresolved reference 'processing'" but I don't know what that means. 
Can someone explain me the error and what should be done?

Comment: Try adding `import processing` after the line `from osgeo import gdal`.

Comment: ok I did that, but now I get the error "algorithm gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer not found" which is strange since I imported processing and gdal...
Also "from osgeo import gdal" is still grayed out.

Comment: The algorithm is called `gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer` (remove the `ogr`). Also, you shouldn't need `from osgeo import gdal` since you're calling the processing module which would contain the algorithm instead, unless you're using `gdal` directly later in your plugin.

Comment: yes, that what one of the problems, thank you for that. Further, I was passing the processing.run() function a set but I need to pass it a dictionary.

Comment: You should also move `Processing.initialize()` outside of the function as it only needs to be executed once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in processing.run("gdalogr:cliprastermymasklayer")](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339713/error-in-processing-rungdalogrcliprastermymasklayer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarise the comments:

1. Include `import processing` as part of importing modules;
2. The algorithm is named `gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer` and not `gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer`;
3. Move `Processing.initialize()` outside the function as it is only required once.